# Lightweight 2D library for embedded linux

Tags: user-interface, embedded, embedded-linux

I'm developing an application on relatively restricted embedded Linux platform, meaning it has 256MB of flash; no problem with RAM however. The application uses SPI TFT screen, exposed through framebuffer driver. The only thing required from UI is to support text presentation with various fonts and sizes, including text animations (fade, slide, etc.). On the prototype, which ran on RPi 3 I used libcairo so it went well. Now, provided the tight space constraints on the real platform, it doesn't seem feasible to use libcairo anymore, since according to what I've seen it requires more than 100 MB of space with all dependencies it has. Note however, that I come from bare metal world and never dealt with complex UI, so I might be completely wrong about libcairo and its size. So guys, please suggest what 2D library I could pick for my case (C++ is preferred, but C is also ok), and just in case there is a way to use libcairo with few megs footprint, please point me to the right direction.

Regards

Comment: Have you tried stripping the binaries (i.e. `strip --strip-unneeded`) for the shared objects for libcairo?

Comment: No, I haven't. I actually lost it while trying to gather all of the dependencies for it.